# Including NPM package into tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, npm, tampermonkey

I want to create a TamperMonkey script that parses some ABI data from EtherScan.io (See: https://github.com/devedse/DeveEtherscanParser).

I now did some poormans ABI decoding but I found out there's a library to do that: https://github.com/jacogr/ethabi-js

How would I go about including this NPM package into my tampermonkey script?

Comment: May not be possible.  Try injecting a `<script type="module"...` tag.  Probably have to use one of the GitHub mirrors that supplies the correct mime type too.

Comment: Yeah but the problem with npm packages is that they consist of 1000's of files. So I can't include it as 1 file.

Comment: If the NPM package is set up "well", then the `<script type="module"...` takes care of all those pesky imports.  Of course there might be a performance hit...

Comment: Personally, if it ever was an issue for me, I'd probably fork the project and set up the build to also construct a single, `@require`able file.

Comment: Any update to this? What if I want to require a generic module/package (like React, or Angular) in my tampermonkey script? Even finding the source as a single JS file is challenging. Guess I'm SoL right?

Comment: You can use a bundler (e.g. webpack) that will do the work for you. However, you will need to create an npm project for this (`package*.json` files `src/`, `dist/`, etc.)

Comment: https://unpkg.com/ might be helpful